# Adding .removeStateDidListener to deinit causes Application to Crash

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, listener, firebaseui

When implementing FirebaseUI in my app I use add a .stateDidChangeListener to listen for changes in the authorization state, but when I try to remove the listener by adding .removeStateDidListener to my deinit my app crashes. Displaying the following in the debug console "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and highlighting the .removeStateDidListener (see picture below). [image: Picture of Error]

I declare the listener like this at the top of my ViewController:

```
var user: User?
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
fileprivate var _authHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle!
```

And here is the code where I implement the listener:

```
func configureAuth() {
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth()]
    authUI?.providers = providers

    // listen for change in authorization state
    _authHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth: Auth, user: User?) in
        if let activeUser = user {
            if self.user != activeUser {
                self.user = activeUser
            }
        } else {
            // user must login
            self.loginSession()
        }
    })
}
```

Could the error be a result of having the NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) in the deinit in addition to the .removeStateDidChangeListener? Is having both redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `_authHandle` is already nil in the `deinit`. Test this if you can. Also note that you do not need to call `removeObserver` method for iOS 9+.

Comment: I also have a Notification observer in my code. Is it still not necessary to call removeObserver? If the _authHandle is already nil can I just leave it without the removeStateDidChange?

Comment: @Notification observer - they are automatically handled by the iOS for iOS version 9+. There was need for removeObserver in previous versions due to crashes for deinited observers receiving notifications. This is no more the case. About `removeStateDidChange` - consider call this method in more appropriate place like `viewWillDisappear` or other, depending on your application logic. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/37642091/3883492 too, it might help you.

Comment: I added it to viewWillDisappear and it seems to be working now.